# rails importing data file.. Discussion topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import

Discussion question:

I have a CSV file that I'm importing into my database through a rails app.

If for some reason the import gets stopped mid way the file has been marked as importing, so it won't import again, but it was not complete.

Some have suggested the first step I take is to import the file data into a table, then I can process records, and if the process is stopped, I can just pick up where I left off. 
The problem I see with this is that the file data that's currently stored as a zip will be exploded into the database, taking up way more room than it needs to. 
I also currently generate a file (response.csv) for each import, that contains the original data, but with a response.

I'm wondering how others have handled this.  What's the "rails" way to import large amounts of data?  What's best practice..

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Import each row separately so that you can pick up where you left
- Use transactions so that the changes are not commited to the db before the operation is complete

Comment: Given that, how would you generate responses?

Comment: If you really want to juggle with the original data - you can just generate the lines of the response on the fly. If you have a transaction and it fails, you just start over fresh. If you have an import that continues, you just continue to append to the file. But if possible, I'd generate the whole response from the database after the import.

Comment: Yeah.. generating the response on the fly isn't practical.. 60k lines per file, and multiple files per zipped import set.  I can see how to switch to the DB though.. Still don't like the idea of importing 20 meg zipped files raw into the database. It feels yuck.